# jquery-booststrap menu doesn't change when page is being resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question. I have a horizontal menu and when I re-size the window, I want my Menu to get changed to bootstrap one. I am writing code in `script.js` and I am not sure if it's correct. If you could help me with this I would be thankful.

```js
if( $(window).width() < 1000)
{
   $( "div" ).removeclass(".nav").addclass(".dropdown") ;
    $( ".dropdown" ).append("<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu
    <span class="caret"></span></button>");
  $( "ul" ).removeclass(".hmenu").addclass(".dropdown-menu") ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you should use css media query

** Try resizing browser while running the below snippet in full page**

```css
/*when screen is bigger than 600px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .dropdown {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
/*when screen is smaller than 600px*/
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .dropdown {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way of doing it. You need to handle this via css media queries. Bootstrap has already defined classes with respect to it.